# Cannot implicity convert type string to List use JavascriptSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I tryed Serialize my *List of phones*:
[image]

in my application, i use javascriptSerializer in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<Phone> GetPhones()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(new TestPhoneService().GetTestData());
        return serializedResult;
    }
```

My Method *GetPhones()* should return phones in *json format*, but i have error:
*Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List...*
May be somebody knows how i can configure *javascript serializer* for resolve it error ? Thanks for your Answers!

Comment: `Serialize()` returns a `string` therefore your `serializedResult` is a `string` and the return type of the method is `List<Phone>`. Change your method return type to `string` if that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my method should return List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `GetPhones()` method is expecting a `List<Phone>` to be returned, however you are currently returning the result of the `Serialize()` method which is going to yield a `string`.

If you want to explicitly return a `List<Phone>`, then you don't really need to serialize your content at all and you could simply return the collection as follows :

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Phone> GetPhones()
{
    return new TestPhoneService().GetTestData();
}
```

Likewise, if you wanted to return a JSON serialized version of your collection, you could try changing your return type to `JsonResult` and using the `Json()` method when returning your collection :

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetPhones()
{
    return Json(new TestPhoneService().GetTestData());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. for use your 1st example, i just wrote the next code in *WebApiConfi.cs* and config json and disable xml forrmatters: 
          *var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
            json.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
            json.Remove(json.XmlFormatter);*

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because [`JavascriptSerializer.Serialize(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `string` but your method returns a list of phones. Change the return type of `GetPhones()` to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

To return Json format from the action method GetPhones(), change the return type from List to ActionResult or JsonResult type. And use return Json(serializedResult) instead of return serializedResult;